# How to tint uitabbar's badge?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

How can I tint uitabbar's badge? Or how to add subview with exactly same position as default badge has. Maybe somebody did such stuff and would like to share with me now?

[image: Such badge]

Comment: Can we have a picture or code of what you mean? This is explanation isnt cutting it for me

Comment: @heinst I added image. Look.

Comment: I have no need to add exactly same badge, change default badge's color is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Look at UITabBar's [`tintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/tintColor) and [`selectedImageTintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/selectedImageTintColor) properties. It's hard to tell what you want from your question, but those are the main ways to change the color of tab bar items.